# Debug java application which is called by script from within docker container

Tags: java, docker, sip, remote-debugging

In our company we use [asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) to build our own voice bot. Asterisk runs a script on incoming calls. This script calls something like `java -cp ./path/to/jarfile.jar`. Asterisk itself runs in a docker container: `CMD asterisk -f`. The java application connects the SIP-channel to the Microsoft BotFramework, that is it sends text from the bot to a text-to-speech-service and vice versa.

Now I want to debug the java application either using Eclipse or IntelliJ or even VS Code. I was not able to get it to work. I followed [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-a-java-application-using-a-dockerfile.html?_ga=2.226819549.1594644085.1573034396-368555906.1573034396) example which was working but I could not apply this to our case.

I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you must **expose the debug port** of your application on your Docker file or Docker-Compose.

Example:

```
ports:
- "9008:9009"
```

Second as the example explain you must configure the type **remote** connection on the IDE, example in Intellij:
[image]

In this case I'm exposing the 9008, so to connect as **localhost** I should use localhost:9008 in the debug configuration on the IDE.

Then you must connect using the Debug mode of your IDE.

[image]